# Kotlin: Internal classes are accessible outside of the package

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am working on creating a library(.aar) for android apps, and i only want 2 of the classes to be visible to the implementer.

`com.example.mylibrary.` is my package name, inside this i have created 1 public class.

```
public object MYSDK {}
```

Then i created 5 other classes in the same package, and all of these classes are not public. I created an **.aar** file, and import it into another project.

The issue is that all of these 6 classes are visible to the user. Although I am not using `public` with other 5 classes, I also tried **internal** but that also didn't help.

I remember, in one of the other project where i was using `JAVA` same structure worked, and all of the classes that were not public were not visible to the user.

Comment: `public` is the default case. Everything is `public` in Kotlin unless declared otherwise. See [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html) for more. The definition of `internal` is hazy (IMHO) and depends a lot on the build system.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Thanks, but in my case "internal" is also making class accessible outside ".aar" package.

Comment: I am importing tha aar file, by going through File->New Module -> Import aar/jar. 
Shouldn't it treat this as a separate module for the app?

Comment: "Shouldn't it treat this as a separate module for the app?" -- I have no idea, sorry. That is a question for JetBrains.

Comment: I wonder how a class that is `internal` can be visible outside of the module? Could you provide a more complete sample?

Comment: @ChristianB : Class is visible but it displays following error message: "Cannot access 'EventsManagement': it is internal in 'com.example.library'" 
But still class is visible to the user in IntelliSense

Comment: You are right, the class is still viewable, but you can not use it when it is `internal`. And it kind of makes sense. The class will not disappear from the jar, because it is used internally. You are just not allowed to access it from outside the module. If you wanna hide its implementation you should think of using ProGuard/R8.

Comment: Sadly there is no package private option in kotlin itseems https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-to-support-package-protected-visibility/1544

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin M13 Blog, published by jetbrains we can see internal keyword is changed to public.

Go through these link:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/09/kotlin-m13-is-out/